# JSON response parsed/not parsed for Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

XMLhttpRequest returns JSON with

`abc.responseType = 'json';`

`var answer = abc.response;`

It works in chrome if I do the following:

```
if (answer.success) {
        window.alert("GOODBOY!");
      } else {
        window.alert("YOUFAILED" + answer.message);
      }
```

However, IE would allways skip the `if` even when `success`was `true`
For it to work in Internet Explorer I tried to parse it (again?)

```
 var answer = abc.response;
 var answer2 = JSON.parse(abc.response);
      if (answer2.success) {
            window.alert("GOODBOY!");
          } else {
            window.alert("YOUFAILED" + answer2.message);
          }
```

Which worked in IE but obviously leads to the following error in chrome:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

What am I missing? How can I make it work on both browsers?

Comment: can you print the value of `abc` using `JSON.stringify(abc, 0, 4);` and check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As IE doesn't support `json` as a `responseType`, drop that, use the default `text` and do

```
 var answer = JSON.parse(abc.response);
```

Comment: That was easy - Thank you I will mark your answer as soon as I'm allowed to